# ::GetTimeZoneInformation() Implementation in c++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I have an application that needs to run anywhere in the world. I want to subtract 8 hours from the current time and get the UTC time difference from the current localtime like -4.00, +5.30, etc.

For example: the current time is 2023:01:25 10:30:25.123 +05.30, and I want to get the time as 2023:01:25 02:30:25.123 +05.30.

I am using `GetLocalTime()` to get local time and `GetTimeZoneInformation()` to get time zone information. In the Indian time zone, it is working correctly by excluding daylight bias, but if I change my timezone to US, it has to use daylight bias for calculating UTC time difference. Also, I am getting one hour difference in the output value.

With the above example, I should get 02 AM in the output time, but I am getting 03 AM (only 7-hour difference instead of 8-hour).

Can anyone please help me with the correct implementation of `GetLocalTime()` and `GetTimeZoneInformation()`?

Comment: 1. Show code. 2. Try SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime().

Comment: @jijesh I noticed that you unaccepted the answer. Was there a problem with it? If you tell me what the problem is, I may be able to improve it.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using the chrono library instead. Since C++20 it has functions for converting between UTC and local time in different time zones.

Example:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    // Get the time zone for India (should be Asia/Kolkata, but it doesn't
    // exist in the database, so I picked Asia/Calcutta):
    const std::chrono::time_zone* tz = std::chrono::locate_zone("Asia/Calcutta");

    // load your time point:
    std::istringstream is("2023-01-25 10:30:25.123 +0530");
    std::chrono::sys_time<std::chrono::milliseconds> tp;
    std::chrono::from_stream(is, "%F %T %z", tp);

    std::cout << tp << '\n'; 

    // go back 8 hours:
    auto minus8h = tp - std::chrono::hours(8);
    std::cout << minus8h << '\n';

    // and get the std::chrono::local_time for Asia/Calcutta:
    auto minus8h_local = tz->to_local(minus8h);
    std::cout << minus8h_local << '\n';
}
```

Possible output:

```
2023-01-25 05:00:25.123
2023-01-24 21:00:25.123
2023-01-25 02:30:25.123
```